# MySQL not using primary index when it had compare with subquery result

Tags: mysql

I has table with the same schema

```
CREATE TABLE `stock` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `currency` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `against` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `time` time NOT NULL,
  `rate` double(8,4) NOT NULL,
  `ask` double(8,4) NOT NULL,
  `bid` double(8,4) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `stock_currency_index` (`currency`),
  KEY `stock_against_index` (`against`),
  KEY `stock_date_index` (`date`),
  KEY `stock_time_index` (`time`),
  KEY `created_at_index` (`created_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=244221 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

When i execute this query mysql has using index

```
mysql> explain select max(id) from stock group by currency;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys        | key                  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | stock | NULL       | range | stock_currency_index | stock_currency_index | 11      | NULL |    2 |   100.00 | Using index for group-by |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+------+----------+--------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Also when i am executing this query mysql has using primary index too

```
mysql> explain select * from stock where id in (244221, 244222);
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | stock | NULL       | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |    2 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

BUT when i am combine these two queries PRIMARY index are not using... i am confused. What i am doing wrong?

```
mysql> explain select * from stock where id in (select max(id) from stock group by currency);
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys        | key                  | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | stock | NULL       | ALL   | NULL                 | NULL                 | NULL    | NULL | 221800 |   100.00 | Using where              |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | stock | NULL       | range | stock_currency_index | stock_currency_index | 11      | NULL |      2 |   100.00 | Using index for group-by |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: A couple of observations: 1) Seriously consider storing date and time as a single entity. 2) It's incredibly unlikely that you would store rate, ask, and bid as anything other than DECIMAL

Comment: @Strawberry thanks a lot for your helpful comment. This relally will be best to use decimal type instead double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try rewriting the query as:

```
select s.*
from stock s join
     (select max(id) as maxid
      from stock
      group by currency
     ) ss
     on ss.maxid = s.id;
```

Second, I would be tempted to put an index on `stock(currency, id)` and to use:

```
select s.*
from stock s
where s.id = (select max(s2.id) from stock s2 where s2.currency = s.currency);
```

Do either of these perform better?

Comment: I haven't yet managed to construct a scenario in which option 2 outperforms option 1

Comment: @Strawberry . . . The correct index would be `stock(currency, id desc)`.  However, MySQL ignores the `DESC`.